# trying to set the dirty value to be true when I click the checkbox in sixth column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

- I am new to kendo.
- I am trying to set the dirty value to be true when I click the checkbox in sixth column.
- but I am getting undefined error.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/0j0ny3v8/

```
$(document).on('change', '#sixthColumnCheck', function() {

  let selectRow = grid.select();
  let gridrow = grid.dataItem(selectRow);
  gridrow.dirty = true;
```

> (index):130 Uncaught ReferenceError: grid is not defined
>
> at HTMLInputElement. ((index):130)
>
> at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>
> at HTMLDocument.i (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: `grid` in not initialized

Comment: the error is pretty well clear i guess, simply follow it and see what is the issue with the variable `grid`

Comment: @TemaniAfif hey I debugged the code but not sure how to proceed...can you update in my fiddle

Comment: @guradio hey can you update in my fiddle ..so confusing...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your grid:

```
var grid = $("#myGridName").data("kendoGrid");
```

or

```
var grid = $("#myGridName").getKendoGrid();
```